# Aligning buttons inside of horizontal linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, button, alignment

I'm trying to align a button inside of a horizontal linear layout to the right side of the screen in my Android application.

How can I do that? **I couldn't find an align option in the properties pane.**  I've tried some Googling, but I couldn't find much since I don't know the correct terms with which to search.

Here's a render so you can get an idea:

[image]

Here's my current `activity_main.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button3" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is easier to use FrameLayout in that case so that you can assign gravity.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical" />
</FrameLayout>
```

If you have to use LinearLayout, you can put an empty view with weight to occupy that space in the middle

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why my question was downvoted? Is it a bad question?

Comment: Not sure, I didn't downvote it. It is not a bad question.